# JavaScript extension for iOS browsers

Tags: javascript, ios, browser, google-chrome-extension

Do any browsers available for iOS support JavaScript extensions?

I thought Google Chrome for iOS might support extensions be it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I don't know any mobile browser that support extension. I have searched for it some times ago. I'm also interest if you find one.

Comment: Google Chrome for mobile doesn't support extension. There're experimental projects to support Chrome Apps on iOS and Android.